# Linux: Ping takes up 400% CPU, java takes up 1000% CPU

Tags: cpu, performance

Here's the specs of my Linux server: 5820k, 32GB RAM, 16TB RAID 10 (6x WD Red Pro 6TB), 1TB 850 Pro SSD, NVIDIA GT 720 GPU.

Basically, the SSD died a few days ago and I had to replace it. I used to have Ubuntu 16.04 installed, but now I have XUbuntu 16.04 installed and I seem to have a problem. Basically, if I go too long without rebooting, random processes start taking up literally ALL of my CPU, and the server becomes unusable without a hard reboot. As you can tell by my specs, this should NOT be happening, when I was on Ubuntu 16.04, it was stable 24/7 for WEEKS absolutely getting hammered with CPU usage.

Here's a picture of the insane CPU usage, do note the 66 hour CPU time on the java process with only 10 hours of uptime, and 40 hours of CPU time on ping with only 7 hours of uptime: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlJkp.jpg

This script here caused 400% CPU usage after several hours even though that script has ran 24/7 for weeks on my old install before with absolutely no issues:http://pastebin.com/DTWizsat

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm really desperate here, I'm going out of town for 3 days now so this is not the best time to be posting it but I'll otherwise forget. I currently have a cron job set to reboot every 4 hours so I do not have to worry about the CPU usage, but this level of instability is an absolute joke to me...

I'm pretty furious, I'm literally about to install Windows Server and just leave it at that, and that's coming from a notorious Linux fanboy.

Thanks.

Comment: So I fixed the java and ping load issues (switched openjdk to oracle, removed the ping script), and now I have a third issue - timesyncd.

The ONLY data I managed to capture was a couple screenshots (https://puu.sh/qsbET/793a3e51f7.png then https://puu.sh/qsbQ2/6dbb87feb9.png), and this output of lsmod: http://pastebin.com/53gnjP8T

It's so weird, as soon as it hit 7 load, it became unresponsive even though I had a script to reboot once it hit 8 load.
I was running Ubuntu 16.04 since beta 1 just fine, I clean install XUbuntu 16.04 and it's NOTHING but problems. Could this be a HW issue?

Comment: It seems several other people seem to be having issues with timesyncd taking up 100% CPU on various flavors of Ubuntu 16.04, I believe that I will need to disable timesyncd once I get access to the server to reboot it, and I guess my other 2 issues were unrelated but solvable issues since I managed to solve them as well..